# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 in windows 7

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working with MongoDB with the Nodejs. I have following index.js file,

```
const express= require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const app= express();

const port=3000;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ThogaKade',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useFindAndModify:false,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(()=>{
    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log(`Server Start on Port ${port}`)
    })
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
})
```

but when I execute `nodemon` command it is en counting following error message here

`MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: for me it seems like mongo databae is not running at all

Comment: I have installed using npm command. it was displayed as sucess. but not in service. how could I check whether is it installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure mongo service is properly installed and started
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/
- User and password are missing in your string. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/
- Use the option [authSource](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) :

  `mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:27017/ThogaKade?authSource=admin`

In this way, you are authenticating on database `admin` and using database `ThogaKade` for connection.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/ too

Comment: mongo service is properly installed and started?

Comment: how could I check this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#mongodb-community-edition-installation-tutorials